# VBScript While file exists

Tags: vbscript

This thing is going to kill me, or I'll kill it.  I can't tell what I'm doing but I keep getting a file not found after I delete the file in a while statement.

```
        MsgBox FSO.FileExists(file.path)'Returns True as a test
        While (FSO.FileExists(file.path))
            If objZip.Items.Item(0).Name = FSO.getfilename(file.path) Then
                FSO.DeleteFile (file.path)
                MsgBox FSO.FileExists(file.path)'Returns False as a test
            End If

            WScript.Sleep 100

        Wend
```

Can someone point me to what I'm doing wrong? I have similar code in another working script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you delete the disk file the reference to it that is stored in the `file` variable is no longer valid. Store the `file.Path` value in a variable and change your code to use it.

```
Dim filePath

    filePath = file.Path
    While FSO.FileExists( filePath )
        FSO.DeleteFile filePath 
    Wend
```

**Note** - Previous code just exposes the approach about how to reference the file. If `DeleteFile` fails (we are looping to remove the file) both error handling and loop wait are needed.

Comment: It's wise to include a `WScript.Sleep 100` in the loop to avoid making the script using resources excessively.

Comment: @Tomalak, Thank you, I know it. The code just exposes the approach in the answer, it is not intended to be bulletproof production code (ex. no error handling of the `DeleteFile` failure that seems will be needed if we must loop until the file could be removed) Code in OP question already includes it

Comment: Not a critique, just an observation - and a hint for the next guy who uses this.

Comment: I did try this, thinking the same thing, with the same results. Granted, I was a bit frustrated at the time and may have missed something, I'll try again.

Comment: Don't script angry. The "File not Found" error I was getting after trying it as a variable was from a different line in the script where I was moving the newly created zip file and was still using file.path. 

Thanks for the help!